# Corrupt Sound File

Tags: html, audio

I have a sound file that only plays in Safari and Opera.  It's In the Mood by Glenn Miller.  Here is a link to the file, [Click Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9MDoEw1FZILai1VNlJHVnVKWjQ/view?usp=sharing).  I have tried putting it through some MP3 audio fixers, but nothing has worked.
I have it implemented through this code below.

```
   <audio id="audioTag" controls loop>
           <source src="sound/background.mp3">
   </audio>
```

Could my could be the problem?

Comment: Could you list the browsers (and version) of those it does not work it?

Comment: All I know it that it works in the newest and multiple slightly order versions of safari (5+ , haven't testing it in any order Safari's past 5+) and opera (22+).  Everything else is doesn't work in